# Vulcanize produces repeated scripts

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, vulcanize

I have created two Polymer custom elements. Both of them uses moment.js. So I have referenced it in both the elements, like:
`<script src="../../bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>`

I use vulcanize to produce a single import file element.html. The issue is that the content of moment.js appears twice in the vulcanized file. 
Is this correct? Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `moment-import.html` in which you include the script, and then import that file in both your elements.

HTML imports are only loaded once across all elements and vulcanize will de-duplicate them for you.

Comment: In fact: there is such a thing already ... https://github.com/bendavis78/moment-element :)